# How to access values of 2d array by pointer from a class?

Tags: c++

In my class as a private member I have a pointer to be initialized to my 2d array:

```
class ConnectFour {
private:
    char(*boardPtr)[6][7];
    static int player;
```

I have a 2d array created in my constructor for my class:

```
ConnectFour::ConnectFour() {
    char board[6][7];
    boardPtr = &board;
    cout << " in constructor" << endl;
    //access indexes of boardPtr by (*boardPtr)[i][j];
    clearBoard();
    
}
```

When I try to set the values for the 2d array as a pointer and print it out the output doesn't look right, like maybe it is printing the address values or something is wrong I'm not sure.

Here is how I assign and print them out:

```
void ConnectFour::clearBoard() {
    //6 rows and 7 columns, initialize all indexes with '-'
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            (*boardPtr)[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}

void ConnectFour::printBoard() {
    cout << "0 1 2 3 4 5 6" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << (*boardPtr)[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I want to access the array as a pointer so that I can return the array from functions.

Comment: The local array char board[6][7]; is not alive after exiting the constructor. So the data member char(*boardPtr)[6][7]; will have an invalid value.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. This fixed my problem.

Comment: You might want to replace the `char(*boardPtr)[6][7];` with a `std::vector<std::array<char,7>> boardPtr(6)`.

Comment: This doesn’t pass a `valgrind` check, does it? 